# Is it alright to change my profile name again?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I have recently changed my name from **BookStriker** to **Invoker**. Honestly, this is my favorite character in a video game.

I changed my profile picture recently and I want to input her name in my profile. And it might be not good enough to change my name again.

Answer (score 10):

As someone who has changed usernames in the past, I'd say this, It's 100% your call.

I changed mine from my original username when I joined this specific SE and added a notice on my profile to let people, from other SEs who know me, know that it's same old me.

It's a feature provided to you by SE and you don't need community consensus or discussion to do so, it's your right. As long as you are not breaking any rules or violating any agreed upon policies or disrupting the site experience in any way whatsoever, you are free to do anything you want. E.g. Change your display picture all you want, but don't be rude to other members etc.

Technically, SE identification is via userIds (Which remain constant) and your associated emails. Nothing crucial in terms of identity is tied to your username.

However, as Mithrandir said, you shouldn't do it if you want people to remember you or associate you with a certain type of posts.

TL;DR, it is purely up to you.

Answer (score 6):

You can only change your display name [once every 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names/38180#38180), so you'll have to wait until 30 days have passed before changing your name again.

I'd advise against changing your name too often though - if you want people to remember you, and associate you with the types of posts that you regularly post, I'd say choose a name and stick with it. Sticking with an avatar isn't a bad idea but is less noteworthy, I think.

Comment: I have to downvote this for advising the OP against changing their name too often. The 30-day rule is the only limit imposed by SE; beyond that, people are **free to change their usernames as often as they want**. If a user changes their name frequently enough to cause some kind of disruption to the site, it might be something for mods to look into, but I can't imagine how name changes could really cause much disruption.

Comment: I personally find it confusing when a user changes their name, especially, but not limited to, when they're active in chat. I realize that not everyone feels that way, though.